# At which point to add one new col to this complex sql

Tags: sql

The following was done some years ago. I have to add one column to the ICBALMIE as col called IESTC$. As I recall this is a complex union so I want to ensure where to put this new col. Do I add to the begginning part or end or both?

```
SELECT LMLTPC, 
       COALESCE(IRLOC1, '') AS irlOC1, 
       COALESCE(IRLOC2, '') AS IRLOC2, 
       COALESCE(IRLOC3, '') AS IRLOC3, 
       iRPRT#, 
       IRQOH#, 
       IRWHS#, 
       ''                   AS IEPRT#, 
       '.00'                AS IEQOH#, 
       ''                   AS IELOC1, 
       ''                   AS IELOC2, 
       ''                   AS IELOC3, 
       ''                   AS IERIDC, 
       ''                   AS IEWHS# 
FROM   (SELECT LMLTPC, 
               LMLOC1, 
               LMLOC2, 
               LMLOC3 
        FROM   ASTDTA.ICLOCMLM 
        WHERE  LMLTPC IN ( 'PAL', 'RAK' ))T1 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT IRLOC1, 
                               IRLOC2, 
                               IRLOC3, 
                               IRPRT#, 
                               IRQOH#, 
                               IRWHS# 
                        FROM   ASTDTA.ICBLDTIR) T2 
                    ON LMLOC1 = IRLOC1 
                       AND LMLOC2 = IRLOC2 
                       AND LMLOC3 = IRLOC3 
UNION ALL 
SELECT ' '   AS LMLTPC, 
       ' '   AS IRLOC1, 
       ' '   AS IRLOC2, 
       ' '   AS IRLOC3, 
       ''    AS IRPRT#, 
       '.00' AS IRQOH#, 
       ''    AS IRWHS#, 
       IEPRT#, 
       IEQOH#, 
       IELOC1, 
       IELOC2, 
       IELOC3, 
       IERIDC, 
       IEWHS# 
FROM   ASTDTA.ICBALMIE
```

Comment: Have a look at my new formatting, isn't it more readable as before? Look if it still works because i have removed some parenthesis.

Comment: thanks i tried but you nail it

Comment: @TimSchmelter just helped out the most with this by removing the superflous parantheses and properly indenting the SQL to make it readable. Adding in a new field now should be a cakewalk. Just make sure the number of fields in your top query match the number of fields in your bottom query and that the fields line up with one-another.  (Wish you could give upvotes to good edits)

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.